# Where to find datasheets in bulk?

Tags: datasheet

Where is collection of data sheets of large table with parameters as columns and models as rows?

Something like:

```
Model        Breakdown_voltage On_resistance <other_values>
QWERTY122AS  120V              6_Ohm         ....
AWERTY123SD  30V               1_Ohm         ....
<all other popular models>
```

for transistors, diodes and other parts.

When searching Google it usually provides data for one/few models or even offer download a PDF file. Where to find it in bulk?

Comment: In the late Paleozoic manufacturers would publish their collected datasheets on things called CD-ROMs. I still have a number of those. For instance the Motorola collection required 2 CDs. That was before DVDs.

Comment: I see there is many disjoint databases per manufacturer, unlikely with standard interface. Is there a comprehensive database of all parts (both currently available and legacy) of all manufacturers with their basic characteristics?

Answer (score 7):

Octopart has an API.  That will give you the PDF's in bulk, subject to rate limits.

Answer (score 6):

Digikey/Mouser parametric search is probably the most useful tool for finding data on a part based on parameters, assuming that's what you want to do

Answer (score 3):

Many manufacturers have parametric tables available for each of their part classes, often available for export to .xls.  For example, [here's Fairchild's discrete MOSFET table](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/tree/power-management/mosfets/discrete-mosfets/).  If you want something very specific, that will probably be the way to go.  You could try compiling these tables.

Different manufacturers will characterize different parameters and use different test setups, so it would be hard to come up with a full list.  However, distributors are in exactly that business.  Either use the Digikey/Mouser search online, or download their catalogs. Digikey's is available as an interactive (downloadable) HTML [here](http://dkc1.digikey.com/us/en/pdf/Current.html), and Mouser's is [here](http://www.mouser.com/CatalogRequest/Catalog.aspx).  Note that these documents are a couple hundred megabytes, and a couple thousand pages.

Comment: I was going to link in Atmel's microcontroller tables, but they seem to have reorganized their website to do away with those.  Can anyone find them?